# "Если..., то..." А нужно ли "то"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Иногда мы говорим: "Если..., то..." Мой вопрос о том, когда частицей "то" можно пренебречь. Пара примеров:

- Если покрасите забор хорошо, повторная покраска будет необязательна.
- Если покрасите забор хорошо, **то** повторная покраска будет необязательна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно говорить и так и эдак.

У меня сложилось такое впечатление, что отсутствие второй части составного союза *"если... то"* характерно для деловой, официальной речи, а для разговорного и литературного языка привычнее употребление *то.* С *"когда... тогда"* вроде другая ситуация: без второго союза речь обычно не теряет своей живости, употребляется он реже.

Так что никто вас не принуждает говорить это *"то",* не хотите — можете опускать его. Но и неправильным его тоже никак не признаешь, он придаёт речи естественность и непринуждённость.